# Check if inner method is called - rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The code is as follows

```
module CompanyFeatures
  class FeatureBuilder
    attr_reader :company, :feature

    def initialize(company, feature)
      @company = company
      @feature = feature
    end

    def call
      return enabled?
    end

    ...

    private

    ...

    def enabled?
      feature[:inherited] ? inherited_configuration : configuration
    end

    def inherited_configuration
      company.inherited_configuration(feature_name)
    end
  end
end
```

I need to confirm that the inherited configuration method is called. The spec is as follows.

```
context 'when inherited is true' do
        let(:feature) { { name: 'feature1', inherited: true } }
        let(:company) { create(:company) }

        before do
          allow(CompanyFeatures::FeatureBuilder).to receive(:inherited_configuration).and_return true
        end

        it 'calls inherited_configuration' do
          expect(described_class.new(company, feature)).to receive(:inherited_configuration)
          described_class.new(company, feature).call
        end
      end
```

But this is returning the error **CompanyFeatures::FeatureBuilder does not implement: inherited_configuration**

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found couple of things in your code:

1. `inherited_configuration` seems to be a private method so that should not be accessible from outside
2. This code you have added in `before` block:

```rb
allow(CompanyFeatures::FeatureBuilder).to receive(:inherited_configuration).and_return true
```

would try to stub a `class` method instead of `instance` method and in rspec you are calling it on an instance.

So it is possible that the error `CompanyFeatures::FeatureBuilder does not implement: inherited_configuration` is on your before block because it is not a class method.